# When using mako template rendering html page, if there is utf-8 character,it's will tell me error

Tags: python, utf-8, mako

The error：

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128.
```

The code:

```
lookup = mako.lookup.TemplateLookup(directories=[template_path] , input_encoding="utf-8", output_encoding="utf-8", encoding_errors="replace" ) 
template = lookup.get_template(filename) 
template.render(**kwargs)
```

Have to manually cast to utf-8 characters can, which is mako birth defects?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, when I used translation functionality with i18n and I had in template file string to be translated with national characters, but without u sign, for example:

```
${'polish word with national character: mózg'}
```

it raised similar exception, you should escape string with 'u' character:

```
${u'polish word with national character: mózg'}
```

You can also try to add coding header on the top of your template file:

```
## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I hope it will solve your problem.